# Category of $\textbf{Ring}$.

Tags: category-theory

I learned that $\textbf{Ring}$ is the category of all nonzero rings with $1$, where morphisms are ring homomorphisms that send $1$ to $1$, in the "Abstract algebra, Dummit and Foote". But I think that it is more reasonable to define it as the category of all rings, where morphisms are ring homomorphisms. Why is $\textbf{Ring}$ defined as above?

Comment: it's sometimes easier to have a convention that excludes slightly trivial or slightly pathological examples.  Dummit and Foote just take a ring to mean something with a unit, they never deal with unit-less rings, and it's extra baggage to carry that around when you aren't using it.

Comment: The category of rings with units normally includes the zero ring, even without Dummit and Foote's blessing. Just look up in wikipedia or nlab: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ring. In this category the zero ring is the terminal object, so it is rather important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both definitions are plausible and have their respective applications. It is only a matter of context.

There is a category of rings with unity as well as a category of rings not necessarily with a multiplicative unity. In the category of rings with unity it makes sense that the morphisms in that category should preserve that additional structure (the $1$), therefore sending unit on unit.

*Notes*:

That these categories really are different can be seen already from simple examples. Consider for example a ring homomorphism (without unity) $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. Then $f(z)=k\cdot z$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $k=f(1)$.

But in the category $\mathrm{Ring}$ the only morphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is the identity, since $f(1)=1$. Also any other morphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$ where $R$ is a ring with unity is uniquely determined: $\mathbb{Z}$ is an (the) initial object in $\mathrm{Ring}$. It is not in the category of rings without unity.

E.g. in fields such as representation theory it is mostly desirable for rings to have a unity, since there one is interested in $R$-modules. 
The identity element in the ground ring induces the identity map of a module $x\mapsto 1\cdot x$.

Comment: But $\{ 0 \}$ is a perfectly good ring with unity!

Comment: @TooOldForMath: That's not true.

Comment: Ok, deleted the comment.